# Classical Hecke eigenforms for $\Gamma_0(p)$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

I am in need of classical eigenforms for $\Gamma_0(p)$.

In particular I need these to be newforms for each of the even weights 8 to 26 and would settle just for cases $p=2,3$ at this moment in time. I need them in a format from which I am able to find critical L-values.

Does anyone know where to find these and/or whether MAGMA/Maple/PARI is able to compute them? (The online documentation for MAGMA doesn't seem to mention commands for finding eigen-bases)

Comment: perhaps that Stein's [tables](http://modular.math.washington.edu/Tables/tables.html) or links at the end will help you...

Comment: William Stein's lectures [Explicitly Computing Modular Forms](http://modular.math.washington.edu/edu/2006/spring/583/book/current.pdf) could perhaps help you too (around page 50). [William Stein](http://modular.math.washington.edu) is maintaining Sage (that includes Pari/Maxima and other free software...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best place to look might be the new "L-functions and modular forms database" website (still in beta at the moment). This has very detailed tables of modular forms, and, better still for your purposes, about their L-functions (critical values, first few zeros on the critical line, etc.); e.g. check out http://www.lmfdb.org/L/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/7/4/0/a/ for lots of info about the L-function of the weight 4 level 7 eigenform.

Comment: Ok so I understand that when the dimension is 1 we can take any such cusp form as an eigenform but what is the best way to find eigenforms when the dimension of the space of new cuspforms is not 1?

Comment: I don't understand your question: the website has tables of new *eigenforms*.

Comment: It doesn't say that, unless I am missing something. It provides a table of new cusp forms.

Comment: Oh sorry I was being stupid, I realise that they are provided!

Comment: Do you know whether the labels given on that site can be used in MAGMA?